# Como encontrar grupos de registros divergentes entre tabelas no SQLite usando chave primária composta?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sqlite

Olá.

Estou construindo um script (Python) para conferir a consistência de dados entre dois meses.

Mensalmente preciso gerar a movimentação contábil daquele mês em arquivo CSV. Desta forma, teoricamente o saldo final do mês anterior em cada conta contábil qualificada deve ser igual ao saldo inicial do mês seguinte para a mesma conta contábil qualificada.

Por conta contábil qualificada entende-se o agrupamento dos seguintes campos de dados (algo como uma chave primária composta):
*ContaContabil, PO, FP, DC, FR, CO, NR, ND, FS, AI*

Assim, num banco de dados SQLite tenho duas tabelas (msc_anterior e msc_atual), cada uma delas com os campos *ContaContabil, PO, FP, DC, FR, CO, NR, ND, FS, AI, Valor, TipoValor, NaturezaValor*

O campo *TipoValor* pode conter *beginning_balance, period_change e ending_balance*. No caso, da tabela *msc_anterior* interessam apenas os registros que possuem `TipoValor = ending_balance`.

Para a tabela tabela *msc_atual* interessam apenas os registros que possuem `TipoValor = beginning_balance`.

Basicamente em preciso comparar se para o conjunto (chave primária composta) *ContaContabil, PO, FP, DC, FR, CO, NR, ND, FS, AI* possuem valores diferentes no campo *Valor* ou no campo *NaturezaValor* filtrando *msc_anterior* com `TipoValor = ending_balance` e `msc_atual = beginning_balance`.

Também precisa considerar que alguns campos podem conter valores *NULL* eventualmente. Mesmo sendo *NULL*, esse valor deve compor a chave primária composta.

O código SQL que estou utilizando (e que não retorna o resultado esperado) é o seguinte:

```
SELECT 
    m0.ContaContabil,
    m1.ContaContabil,
    m0.PO,
    m1.PO,
    m0.FP,
    m1.FP,
    m0.DC,
    m1.DC,
    m0.FR,
    m1.FR,
    m0.CO,
    m1.CO,
    m0.NR,
    m1.NR,
    m0.ND,
    m1.ND,
    m0.FS,
    m1.FS,
    m0.AI,
    m1.AI,
    m0.Valor,
    m1.Valor,
    m0.NaturezaValor,
    m1.NaturezaValor
FROM 
    (SELECT 
            * 
    FROM msc_anterior 
    WHERE TipoValor LIKE 'ending_balance') m0,
    (SELECT 
            * 
    FROM msc_atual 
    WHERE TipoValor LIKE 'beginning_balance') m1
WHERE
    (
        m0.ContaContabil = m1.ContaContabil
        AND m0.PO = m1.PO
        AND m0.FP = m1.FP
        AND m0.DC = m1.DC
        AND m0.FR = m1.FR
        AND m0.CO = m1.CO
        AND m0.NR = m1.NR
        AND m0.ND = m1.ND
        AND m0.FS = m1.FS
        AND m0.AI = m1.AI
    )
    AND (
        m0.Valor != m1.Valor
        OR m0.NaturezaValor != m1.NaturezaValor
    )
```

Um banco de dados de exemplo está disponível em https://github.com/everton3x/everton3x.github.io/blob/master/cache.db

Agradeceria a ajuda!